# Why is appended radio button is not clickable?

Tags: jquery

I have done a small mistake in my code that is not allowing me to click on the appended radio button.

```
var ToBeRadio=NoneElementsArray[i]*1-1;
$(this).children('td:eq('+ToBeRadio+')').find('input:checkbox').hide();
$(this).children('td:eq('+ToBeRadio+')').append("<input type='radio'>");
```

Where's the error?

Comment: What exactly is happening. Is the checkbox disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your input type a name attribute. Your code should be similar to:

```
 var ToBeRadio=NoneElementsArray[i]*1-1;
 $(this).children('td:eq('+ToBeRadio+')').find('input:checkbox').hide();
 $(this).children('td:eq('+ToBeRadio+')').append("<input name='myRadios' type='radio'>");
```

Comment: This shouldn't prevent his from clicking on it, though.

Comment: I think he can click on it. It just won't make the radio button selectable. At least that's what happens to me when I put his code into a page and run it through all versions of IE in IE Tester.

Comment: Works fine for me, its just not unclickable. http://jsfiddle.net/jameswiseman/gn2Rp/2/